# How do you handle function parameters in svelte?

Tags: svelte

I am trying to get the html5 spec for geolocation to work in svelte. I can't figure out how to get the showPosition function parameter to kick in.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>

function getLocation() {
    console.log('This code runs when the button is clicked');
  if (navigator.geolocation) {      
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);    
  } 
}

function showPosition(position) {
    console.log('this code never runs');

    const lng = position.coords.longitude;
  const lat = position.coords.latitude;

  console.log(`longitude: ${ lng } | latitude: ${ lat }`);
}
</script>

<button on:click="{getLocation}">Try It</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got nothing Svelte specific in your JS, if it works out of Svelte, it should work here.

My guess is that the success callback that you're passing is not called because you're not getting success, but an error. For example, if you're denied access to your position the first time the browser asked for your domain (localhost:something presumably), then future requests are silently denied. And you get and error.

You should have a error callback too:

```js
const onSuccess = console.log.bind(console, 'success')

const onError = console.error.bind(console, 'error')

const options = {
  // ...
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options)
```

See [API docs (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) for details & available options.

With this code, in Svelte or not, you should see something happening in your browser's console.

Comment: Thank you rixo! Actually it works like a charm in jsfiddle or on w3schools. Once I put in an error callback, i did see what the error was. "Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy." Further research into the error, it seems that the REPL is blocking it. I plan on creating a local project instead of on the REPL.... and I am assuming it will function. Thanks again!

Comment: Rixo, I built it locally and it does work as expected. Thanks again!